# Loading of Django test fixtures into database

Tags: python, django, sqlite, testing, pycharm

I'm trying to do some test-driven development and would find it useful to look inside the database to see what's being done using database tools in PyCharm.

I load up the test fixture here:

```
    case6_fixtures = ['test_case6.json']
    try:
        call_command('loaddata', *case6_fixtures, verbosity=9)
    except Exception as ex:
        print(str(ex))
```

And it seems to be loading.

```
Loading 'test_case6' fixtures...
Checking '/Users/user/Workspace/application/application/fixtures' for fixtures...
Checking '/Users/user/Workspace/project' for fixtures...
No fixture 'test_case6' in '/Users/am034402/Workspace/project'.
Installing json fixture 'test_case6' from '/Users/user/Workspace/application/application/fixtures'.
Processed 2 object(s).
Installed 2 object(s) from 1 fixture(s)
```

If I try to query it with the Django ORM, I get a record back, and it matches what is in   the fixtures file. However, if I query the sqlite3 db file that is supposed to have something in it (testing.db):

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
        'TEST': {
            'NAME': 'testing.db'
        }
    }
}
```

nothing's there. The same can be said for db.sqlite3. Yes, the tables are there, but they're empty.

I'm thoroughly confused. Does Django's test runner load these fixtures into memory or something? Shouldn't there be data in those database tables in testing.db?

Comment: After each test execution database is cleaned by default. I suggest checking how to disable db recreation on each test run.

Comment: Tests are run in transactions, which are rolled back as soon as the test finishes.  If you load the fixtures during model migrations, and run your tests with --keepdb, you'll be able to see the fixtures data in the tables.

Comment: @TimNyborg would this be the case when hitting a breakpoint in PyCharm? I can see that the db gets wiped with each test run, but the specific test has not completed when I am checking the database in this example. It's mid-test.

Comment: I suspect that almost any method of querying the database will be outside the transaction (on a different connection), and unable to see uncommitted changes (the fixtures).   Not certain about SQLite, though, as it handles transactions differently than most.